# PHP Nested Loop. How on the second loop print items according to the id of the first loop?

Tags: php, nested-loops

I need to print a wine list from a database.
I need to print at first a categorie and after all the items that are inside. Thats the order. And i have multiple categorie. So at the end the result will be categorie1, many items, categorie2 many items...

This is the code that i write from now: I think that my problem is to print items according to the id of the alcool_categorie !!

```
$q_vine = "SELECT * FROM alcool_categorie ";
$r_vine = mysql_query($q_vine,$connection);
$n_vine = mysql_num_rows($r_vine);
$q_bouteille = "SELECT * FROM alcool_item where ALCNID = '$alid'";
$r_bouteille = mysql_query($q_bouteille,$connection);
$n_bouteille = mysql_num_rows($r_bouteille);
for($i = 0; $i < $n_vine; $i++){
    echo mysql_result($r_vine,$i,'named').'<br/><br/>';
    for($z = 0; $k < $n_bouteille; $k++){
        echo mysql_result($r_bouteille,$k,'name').'<br/>';
    }       
}
```

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated and should not used anymore. Use `MySQLi`, or `PDO_MySQL` instead. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: If you wanna keep track of the last item, just save it in a variable

Comment: `for($z = 0; $k < $n_bouteille; $k++){` spot the problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to use a "JOIN" in your query and then order the rows in the way you want them to be ordered, then you'll only need one loop. While running the loop you compare the category name with the previous category name and if it changes display the category name.

Example

```
$sql    = "SELECT categoryName, bottleName FROM category INNER JOIN bottle ON category.categoryId = bottle.categoryId ORDER BY category.categoryId";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$connection);

$categoryName = ''; //just to make sure the first time the Category is named

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($categoryName != row['categoryName']){
        $categoryName = row['categoryName'];
        echo '<h1>'.$categoryName.'</h1>';
    }
    echo row['bottleName'].'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this after correctly giving the category `id` field name in the query and inside the first `while` loop.

```
$q_vine = "SELECT id, named FROM alcool_categorie ";
$r_vine = mysql_query($q_vine,$connection);
$n_vine = mysql_num_rows($r_vine);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_vine)) {
  $categories[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$q_bouteille = "SELECT name, ALCNID FROM alcool_item ";
$r_bouteille = mysql_query($q_bouteille,$connection);
$n_bouteille = mysql_num_rows($r_bouteille);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_bouteille)) {
  $items[$row['ALCNID']] = $row;
}

foreach ($categories as $category_id=>$category) {
  echo "<ul><li>{$category['named']}<ul>";
  foreach ($items[$category_id] as $item) {
    echo "<li>{$item['name']}</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul></li></ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into PHP's [foreach](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct. Foreach loops through an entire array of results, for each element inside the array, it extracts its value and optionally also its key. This will not require the use of mysql_num_rows.

Instead of calling mysql_result, you could use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to get a row's value from your mysql_query. The row's To get all values, you can incorporate this into a loop even. If you do the latter, you can create your own array of key/value pairs and use this inside a foreach construct.

Also note that the use of mysql is outdated, you will want to use mysqli now, which is very similar to mysql.